# Зачем нужен метод Arrays.asList()?

Tags: java

Зачем нужен метод Arrays.asList() ? В чем его суть?

Comment: чтобы представить массив в виде списка, очевидно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Как и следует из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)): формирует список на основе массива. Массив при этом используется для внутреннего представления списка. Таким образом сохраняется связь между списком и исходным массивом:

- изменения в массиве отразятся на списке:

  ```
  String[] a = { "foo", "bar", "baz"};
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);
  System.out.println(list); // [foo, bar, baz]

  a[0] = "aaa";
  System.out.println(list); // [aaa, bar, baz]
  ```
- изменения в списке отразятся на массиве:

  ```
  String[] a = { "foo", "bar", "baz"};
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);
  System.out.println(list); // [foo, bar, baz]

  list.set(0, "bbb");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // [bbb, bar, baz]
  ```

Если массив содержит объекты, очевидно, и массив и список будут ссылаться на одни и те же экземпляры:

```
Object[] a = { new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(a);
System.out.println(a[0] == list.get(0)); // true
```

---

Как уже упомянул *@Oleg Chiruhin*, тот факт, что метод принимает в качестве параметра массив в форме аргументов переменной длины, позволяет использовать его для относительно удобной инициализации списков:

```
List<Foo> list = Arrays.asList(new Foo(...), new Foo(...), new Foo(...));
```

сравните с

```
List<Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Foo(...));
list.add(new Foo(...));
list.add(new Foo(...));
```

Answer (score 10):

Кроме того что описано в JavaDoc, практическая суть этого метода в том, что довольно часто на вход метода нужно прислать именно список, элементы которого заранее известны (н-р какой-то набор магических констант, что часто требуется для быстрого написания TDD-тестов). Но для инициализизации списка in-place, прямо по месту вызова, в Java нет красивого синтаксиса. Поэтому можно вызывать это просто в синтаксисе `mymethod(Arrays.asList("Новосибирск", "Москва", "Кукуево"))`. Заметьте, что я смог провести инициализацию листа даже внутри предложения на русском языке!

Answer (score 2):

Следует помнить, что метод Arrays.asList() возвращает **немодифицируемый** List, причём эта немодифицируемость сохраняется при сериализации/восстановлении списка.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос